# How to get the ICCID of the SIM card that is in the iPhone using my iOS App?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, mobile

A SIM card contains **ICCID** (*International Circuit Card ID*). The **ICCID** is unique in the world. I need my app get the **ICCID** of the **SIM card** that is in the **iPhone**. Does anyone know whether it is possible, and if possible, how to do?

Answer (score 3):

Are you going to submit your app to the AppStore? If so you need to know that Apple rejects any application accessing SIM card because they supposed that such behaviors break the user privacy and security, also there is no way in the official SDK to read anything from the SIM card. Anyway there are some Private APIs out there that lets you access those SIM card information, but obviously your application will be rejected since Private APIs are not allowed on the AppStore.

Comment: No, the application will not be submitted to the Apple Store. It is an enterprise application that will be distributed by the Distribution Certificate (if possible). It is one of the minimum requirements that the application take the ICCID of the SIM card. This procedure we are already doing with the Android app.

Comment: Well in that case you'll need to jailbreak your device(s) first. Also you won't able to use the regular iOS simulator bundled in XCode since an unjailbroken device and the iOS simulator won't give you access to those informations. Anyway you can try Apple's IOKit.framework which can give you access to those infos but, even if it's a public framework, Apple doesn't allow devs to use it.

Comment: Understand. It is undesirable for the company to make this type of procedure. I appreciate the answers. Let's see if we should proceed with the project.

Comment: Private APIs are not allowed on the AppStore :((
Face time used Private APIs so, it is not allowed on the AppStore :((( @Aluminum

Answer (score 2):

According to my research, there are private APIs that can help you to get IMSI and IMEI but they will not be admissable by Apple and your application will be rejected at the store.